# How apply new mapping with bulk api in Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping

I use `bulk` API to copy documents from a remote elasticseach to the local one. I would like to apply new mapping. In the first function I apply new mapping as bellows:

```
def create_mapping(es, idx, document_type):
    mymapping = {"mappings": {document_type: { \
        "properties": { \
            "prijs": {"type": "integer"},\
            "datum": {"type": "date"},\
            "kilometerstand": {"type": "integer"}
            }}}}

    if es.indices.exists(index=idx):
        es.indices.delete(index=idx)

    es.indices.create(index=idx, body=mymapping)
```

And in the second function I use `bulk` to copy the documents:

```
def copy_index(remote_es, local_es, idx):
    ....
    bulk(local_es, response_list, chunk_size=5000)
```

But I get the error: `document(s) failed to index`

**Edit**

If I add multiple two documents by `bulk` it shows:

```
raise BulkIndexError('%i document(s) failed to index.' % len(errors), errors) BulkIndexError: (u'2 document(s) failed to index.', [{u'index': {u'status': 400, u'_type': u'kliks', u'_index': u'logstash-2018.02.07', u'error': {u'caused_by': {u'reason': u'Invalid format: "2018-02-07 01:00:51" is malformed at " 01:00:51"', u'type': u'illegal_argument_exception'}, u'reason': u'failed to parse [datum]', u'type': u'mapper_parsing_exception'}, ....
```

Comment: I think, it is because some of your documents don't have values in `datum` field.

Comment: @AshwaniShakya thank you for the hint. You are right. When I exclude `datum` from mapping, it works. So how can I define the mapping for the fields that sometimes don't have values?

Comment: fill `datum` field as `null` if it is not available.

Comment: I cheked the `datum`. It is not `null`, but when I remove it from mapping, everything works.

Comment: Can you get the detailed error message of why it failed to index a specific document? [`bulk()`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk) returns a list of errors.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev I added the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified the `date` format and the error fixed:

```
"datum": {"type": "date", "format":"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
```